# Naming conventions for series

Tags: discussion

In my old [thread](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/ending-of-bloody-monday-season-3?noredirect=1#comment16009_5691), I originally had the question titled as Bloody Monday Last Season because that is the actual series name. Bloody Monday was the first manga in this series, and then it had a sequel called Blood Monday 2 Pandora's box, then a final sequel named [Bloody Monday Last Season](http://myanimelist.net/manga/26260/Bloody_Monday:_Last_Season).

The current name of the series in the title has been changed to Bloody Monday season 3, but wouldn't it make more sense to just call it Bloody Monday Last Season? Perhaps I need to insert the colon to make it more distinguishable.

Anyhow, how should we name the series with sequels?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the tags you have on the question, like "bloody-monday" indicate the overall series well enough, so that any version of the season name which is commonly used should be easily identifiable.

There would be a lot of work trying to enforce naming conventions on season titles, when the mods already have many series that have duplicate names anyway (an English version and Japanese version for example)

If in doubt, you could always refer to it as "the third season of Bloody Monday"